# Implementing attack animation in four direction movement

Tags: c#, 2d, unity

The way the program is supposed to run is basically, a character can be running/idle and if spacebar is pressed, all movement stops and movement controls are locked through the bool "canMove". The integer shockwave is a 1-4, directly correlating to the direction 1-4 (1 = north, 2 = east, 3 = south, 4 = west). Then, the animation plays and when it is over the controls are unlocked and you can move freely.

The problem I have encountered is, I can find no way to specifically tell when the animation is ending inside of a blend tree. I cannot find a way to allow the animation to play, and then continue to unlock the controls.

Since this site won't let me post more than three links, I will have to describe the animator window. Basically I have four idle states (N, E, S, W). Each motion is a blend tree, and each state is connected with a transition purely based off of int direction.

[image: Blend Tree]

This is where I tried adding another motion to the blend tree called shockwave, based on threshold speed (-1). This worked up until the point that I realized I would not be able to add anymore attacks or states, and that I could not tell when the animation had finished in order to unlock the controls.

[image: Blend Tree Inspector]

```
void Update (){

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)){

        canMove = false;
        direction = animator.GetInteger ("Direction");
        animator.SetFloat ("Speed", 0.0f);

        if (direction == 1){
            animator.SetInteger("Shockwave", 1);
            animator.SetFloat ("Speed", -1.0f);

            //find a way to detect that the attack animation is done.
            //continue and allow movement
            canMove = true;

                }
            }

        else if (direction == 2){
            animator.SetInteger ("Shockwave", 2);
            //if(!anim.IsPlaying ("character_shockwave_2")){
                //canMove = true;
            //}
        }
        else if (direction == 3){
            animator.SetInteger ("Shockwave", 3);
            //if(!anim.IsPlaying("character_shockwave_3")){
            //  canMove = true;
            //}
        }
        else if (direction == 4){
            animator.SetInteger ("Shockwave", 4);
            //if(!anim.IsPlaying("character_shockwave_4")){
                //canMove = true;
            //}
        }
```

Attempted solutions:

I have tried to use waitforseconds(x), and just wait for the attack animation to finish, and then after that amount of seconds I would set the canMove bool to true. For whatever reason, I cannot get this to work.

I have also tried to directly find if the animation is done playing through a few different ways, but I learned that the blend tree does not allow this.

The only solution I have thought might work is actually manually playing all animations through code alone. (Would require re writing the entire program).

If any further code is needed, I can supply it.

Comment: Have you tried using "OnStateExit" ?  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours

Comment: "OnStateExit is called on the last frame of a transition to another state." Would this apply to transitions inside of a blend tree?

Comment: This would be a script that you attach to your Animator's State.  So every single time that you would exit a state with this script attached, you could execute some code.   I can add an example below, but it is pretty self-explanatory from the link I provided.

Comment: Going to try and implement this in the next hour and a half. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Would you look at that, it works. I added the BaseSMB script to the shockwave state using regular transitions between the attack and the idle state. Thanks for your help, if you can put it as an answer I will select it.

Comment: Done.  Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hooking into the Unity OnStateExit?

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/state-machine-behaviours

This will allow your state machine to execute code every time you exit a state.